# Data not displaying from database

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and trying to display data from the database.

However it only displays data from one row but I want to show the data from multiple rows where the condition match. Here is my code I am using:

```
<?PHP


session_start();

if (!(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != '')) {

header ("Location: checklogin.php");
}

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "map_my_way");
$fetch_row = $_SESSION['username'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members where username='$fetch_row'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $email = $row['email'];
    $m_no = $row['m_no'];
    $v_name = $row['v_name'];
    $capacity = $row['capacity'];
    $fuel_type = $row['fuel_type'];

}

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT s_a_name FROM locations where  username='$fetch_row'");

$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);


?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Profile Page</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="profile.css">
    </head> 
        <body id="body">
        <div id="mmw"> <span> MAP MY WAY </span></div>
        <div id="title_box">
                <a href="profile.php"><button id="lvbutton">My Profile</button></a>
                <a href="user_index.php"><button id="lvbutton">Maps</button></a>
                <a href="edit.php"><button id="lvbutton">Edit Profile</button></a>
                <a href="logout.php"><button id="lvbutton" style="float:right; margin- right:10px;">Sign-Out</button></a>

        </div>

            <div id="box">
                    <div id="name_box"><span>Welcome <?php echo($_SESSION['username']); ?></span></div>
                    <div id="box1">
                            <div> <p id="link">Your Information </p>

                                <ul style="margin-top:20px; padding-left:0;">
                                        <li><span>First Name : <?php echo $first_name; ?></span></li><br>
                                        <li><span>Last Name : <?php echo $last_name; ?></span></li><br>
                                        <li><span>Email : <?php echo $email; ?></span></li><br>
                                        <li><span>Age : <?php echo $m_no; ?></span></li><br>
                                        <li><span>Current Vehical : <?php echo $v_name;  ?></span></li><br>
                                        <li><span>Fuel Type: <?php echo $fuel_type; ?> </span></li><br>
                                        <li><span>Seating Capacity : <?php echo     $capacity; ?></span></li><br>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="box2">     <p id="link">Saved Routes </p>
                                <ul style="margin-top:20px;">
                                       <span> <?php foreach($row2 as $data) 
                                                    {echo "route Name : $data <br>"  ; }; 
                                                ?>
                                    </span>
                                </ul>
                    </div>   
            </div> 
         </div>
        </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You're over-writing all your variables in the loop; when it ends, it's only the last one that's set

Comment: I quote from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24547475/) - *"it worked i did both and the code is working now thanks a lot."* - So, what is it now and what's changed since? Did you have a "working" copy to revert to?

Comment: how to overcome that @andrewsi please tell me.

Comment: @user3800570 - the easiest way is to move your while loop down to the inside of your table. Inside your loop, instead of assigning the variables, you can echo them out, with the correct HTML added.

Comment: @Fred-ii- on that i was trying do display user data that did not repeat for one user and now the nature of the data is repeating. that changed.

Comment: I don't know if `<?PHP` works - even if it does, it is usual to write this in lower case.

Comment: @andrewsi the data which is not displaying is the other one which i am recalling at the saved routes which you said that i am over-writing.. please tell me how to solve that over-writing

Comment: @user3800570 - oh, mea maxima culpa. It's very unusual to put a while loop around `mysqli_fetch_array`, if you're only fetching one row :)

Comment: @user3800570 - the issue is the inverse of what I thought. You actually need to put a loop around the `$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);` part - you're just getting back a single row from the database, and then running through that row.

Comment: @andrewsi how please tell my knowledge is not much in PHP just correct my code please.

Comment: @user3800570 - would you like to have a go by yourself first? You've got most of the code you need already, you just need to change things around. The `while` loop you have will go through the results from your database, so you need to do something just like that for `$row2`. If you put that `while` loop inside the second `<ul>`, you shouldn't need to change much else at all.

Comment: @andrewsi as you say i had tried this what you say but it only works if the data is in one row but i have data which is in multiple rows so what i understand from what you are saying i have tried this and not worked.

Comment: @user3800570 - could you edit your question, and add in your updated code? What is happening when you run it? If you've added the foreach loop, you should be getting something through, or at the least, an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your query on the members table is only going to return one row, so you don't really need to have `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)` in a loop (that shouldn't break your script, though). Your query on the locations table will potentially return more than one row, so you do need to loop on that one. Something like:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT s_a_name FROM locations where  username='$fetch_row'");
$savedRoutes = "";

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
  $savedRoutes .= "route Name : " . $row2['s_a_name'] . "<br/>";
}
```

will put all the data together in a string ($savedRoutes) that can be echoed down in the "Saved Routes" section of your html code.

Alternatively, you can put the loop down in the "Saved Routes" section and just echo out each line as you loop through. Personally I think putting the loop in the top and concatenating the data into a string is a bit cleaner and easier to read.